# Freeform edit entry order issue

Tags: solspace-freeform, entry

I know this issue has been mentioned before, but I can't find a solution to the problem anywhere.

I don't understand why when you edit a a form submission, the fields don't appear in the order they have been set in. I know you can edit how they appear in the main entries listings, but this doesn't carry over to the edit page for each individual entry.

I've tried to edit the plugin to do this, but am getting no where.

Has anyone else found a solution to this?

Thanks.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

The order the fields are displayed is based on the order they are in in the field definition section of the form configuration.  I just tested moving several fields around, and the edit form reflects the changes.  I am assuming that you are referring to the entry edit in the CP and not the freeform:edit tag. Just drag them into the position you'd like.

Comment: Can you please clarify how I get to the page to reorder them? I can't seem to find it anywhere!

Comment: Anyone able to help?